# Can't run JAR files because of outdated JRE but updating it does nothing

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I tried to open the jar with "java -jar blah.jar".
this is the outcome:

```
java -jar Desktop/lambertone2.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: main/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56) .
```

I went to Oracle site to download the latest JRE but it doesn't change anything.
All this happened some day ago where the update section of java told me to erase java because it was obsolete, so i removed it and reinstalled it.
if i use the command java --version it says me that the command is unsupported.
if i use javac --version it says that it is version 10.

Comment: I think it's `java -version` (not `--version`). It's likely that you're running on the incorrect java version

Comment: Do you have 2 JRE installed and the `java` is pointing to the older one?

Comment: how do i check if i have 2 jre? -version says 1.8 btw

Comment: You can change JAVA_HOME to Java 10.  And add it to path variable.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/
Or just launch your jar as `<pathToJava10>/ java - jar blah.jar`
Because bytecode version 54 it's java 10, and your jdk is 8 (bytecode 52)

Comment: this is what i have on .bash_profile file
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
is this the problem?
how do i have to change the path?

Comment: `export JAVA_HOME= <path to java bin directory>`
for example `export JAVA_HOME= /usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk-amd64/bin`.
`java -version` must return  10 version of java

Comment: the variable in my .bash_profile points to this path . 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
the only other JVM in the java virtual machines folders is the 9.0.
The variable points to the 10 version tho.  
Sorry but i don't understand what should i do.

Comment: What files are under `. /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`. JAVA_HOME should contain directory where 'java' executable is placed.

Comment: in the home folder there's a bunch of folders among which figures the bin/ folder . 
inside the bin folder there are binaries, also a java* one.  
should i modify the HOME variable to point to the bin folder?

Comment: Yep. To bin folder.

Comment: i did it and doesn't work :(.  
still tells me that the java version is 1.8